# How can one use online backup with large amounts of static data?

Tags: backup

I'd like to setup an offsite backup solution for about 500GB of data that's currently stored between my various machines. I don't care about data retention rates, as this is only a backup of, not primary storage, for my data. If the backup is stored on crappy non-redundant systems, that does not matter.

The data set is almost entirely static, and mostly consists of things like installers for Visual Studio, and installer disk images for all of my games.

I have found two services which meet most of this:

- Mozy
- Carbonite

However, both services impose low bandwidth caps, on the order of 50kb/s, which prevent me from backing up a dataset of this size effectively (somewhere on the order of 6 weeks), despite the fact that I get multiple MB/s upload speeds everywhere else from this location. Carbonite has the additional problem that it tries to ignore pretty much every file in my backup set by default, because the files are mostly iso files and vmdk files, which aren't backed up by default.

There are other services such as EC2 which don't have such bandwidth caps, but such services are typically stored in highly redundant servers, and therefore cost on the order of 10 cents/gb/month, which is insanely expensive for storage of this kind of data set. (At $50/month I could build my own NAS to hold the data which would pay for itself after ~2-3 months) (To be fair, they're offering quite a bit more service than I'm looking for at that price, such as offering public HTTP access to the data)

Does anything exist meeting those requirements or am I basically hosed?

Comment: *prevent me from backing up a dataset of this size effectively (somewhere on the order of 6 weeks)* — and that's only for creating the backup. Don't forget that you might need to *restore* as well, which can use totally different figures.

Comment: Why do you still need your Visual Studio installers? I downloaded mine. Installed. Then deleted the ISO. If you need to uninstall, just download it again or burn a DVD.

Comment: @Cole: not an option for everyone. When this question was written I had gotten the Visual Studio installer from an academic subscription system run by the university that did not allow repeated downloads. (Now I have an MSDN subscription to use but it is 3 years later...)

Comment: Amazon recently reduced their prices, you might look at them again.  See [my answer below](http://superuser.com/a/743438/105516)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what I ended up going with is that service called [CrashPlan](http://crashplan.com), which is similar to Mozy and Carbonite but doesn't throttle (and the client is actually pretty decent even without the offsite backup bit).

Answer (score 2):

I would personally take a look at cheaper dedicated servers or virtual private servers that have bigger hard drives / the ability to add storage.

This will still be expensive, but nothing compared to a "cloud" solution.

Another option available to you, which is worth a shot - find a host that has an "unlimited" plan and see just how unlimited it is, you never know, you may get lucky.

Comment: Do you have any examples? Even the cheapest PS solutions I can find are on the order of $100/month, and only have ~200GB worth of storage.

Comment: Godaddy - $5 for a service that states 150GB or $9 for their "unlimited", by that, it must be a minimum of 150GB, I don't know how much you will actually get. Dedicated server with 240GB (2x120GB) is less than £30 a month, I don't really like Godaddy, but it was just an example, and there are many places that offer similar packages.

Comment: Sorry, tried posting that before but site went offline.

Answer (score 1):

[backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) might be what you're looking for - 5 dollars a month per computer, unlimited storage, and should you really need it, they mail you cds or hard drives with your data for a fee.  They claim not to throttle either, and have a speedtest on their site.

Comment: Except they refuse to back up ISO files or VMDK files, the main things I need saved. :( Otherwise looks promising +1.

Comment: maybe zip em up or some other container file ? both of those should zip pretty well

Answer (score 0):

http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=8971

Godaddy offers unlimited space and bandwidth for under $10 a month.  Note, there's no referral link and I'm not plugging them, this is just the easiest solution I thought of.

edit: whoops, missed this caveat.
"
Plan provides unlimited storage subject to availability of space on a single clustered server and subject to the Terms of Service in your Hosting Service Agreement. Limitations apply to other plan features.
"

Comment: Yes .. web host "unlimited" plans usually aren't really :(

Answer (score 0):

There's companies like Mezolink, who specialize in such larger quantities of data backup for small and midsize businesses: http://www.mezolink.com/services/online-backups.aspx

They use our BackupAgent platform for this.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon recently reduced their prices, you might want to look at them again.

I'm able to [backup all my data to Amazon S3](http://blog.kyletraff.com/automatically-backup-files-to-amazon-cloud/) for less than a dollar a month, though it looks like your backup would cost a few dollars more.  If you're smart about which data you need to backup as well as make sure you use a good compression tool like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) you could probably save quite a bit of money.  If you opt for reduced redundancy storage, [you're in even better shape pricewise](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).  Bandwidth has never been an issue for me.

You can do this manually or [write a small python script](https://gist.github.com/ktraff/10733224) to do it automatically for you.